# How to restore mysql db from dump file when one column contains sha2 hash?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Current DB: Mariadb 10.5,
dump file from Mariadb 10.4,
OS: Arch Linux recent install

The dump file is about 10MB including a lot of text strings, some 200-300 words long.  The following is an error that stopped the dump file from being fully loaded.

`[root@mymachine ~] mysql -u root -p mydb < ~/jump/dump.sql`

> ERROR 2005 (HY000) at line 703: Unknown MySQL server host 'Louis10UnBarron' (-2)

The formatting of the above error msg is a little different than I'm presenting: Barron (-2) is actually on the line below under the 'n' so it appears as if a line break and additional spaces are there.

When I open the dump file in SublimeText the strings are intermingled with hexidecimals.

I thought the character sets were mismatched so I adjusted the new database's default set to match the old one, utf8.  When I look at the charset for each table both the new and old tables are using latin1.

I'm lost for ideas on what to do next.  Thanks for any help.

Addendum:
I realized one of the columns in the table giving me problems is a sha2 hash.  I guess the column type (varbinary) doesn't affect how mysql reads the data.

Addendum #2:
I can't be the first person to encounter this issue.  Storing a hash in a database must be a common way of verifying a text entry has not been changed.  There must be a way to restore a database from a dump file when one column is a hash!

Answer (score 0):

There are some incomparability between 10.4 and 10.5.

That is why MariaDb offers a upgrade tutorial, which has to be peroformed

see [manual](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/upgrading-from-mariadb-104-to-mariadb-105/)

The Point 7

> Run mysql_upgrade.
>
> mysql_upgrade does two things:
> Ensures that the system tables in the#mysql database are fully compatible with the new version.
> Does a very quick check of all tables and marks them as compatible with the new version of MariaDB

is vital to perform at the end

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to access the 10.4 database as the machine running it will no longer boot up.  I'm stuck with just the .sql file from the dump.

Comment: unistall 10.5 install 10.4 make the pupgrade path and then unistall 10.5 and install 10,5, If that is impossible, make a vm and installing there the yastem an 10.4 .....

Comment: Version 10.4 mariadb produced the same error.

Comment: dekete this question and ask in DBA https://dba.stackexchange.com with all information